# preventing OpenJPA N+1 select performance problem on maps

Tags: performance, jpa, select, dictionary

When I have an entity that contains a Map, e.g.

```
@Entity
public class TestEntity {
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    Map<String, String> strings = new HashMap<String, String>();
}
```

and I select multiple entities (SELECT z FROM TestEntity z), OpenJPA 2.0 performs one query for each TestEntity to fetch the map, even though I used FetchType.EAGER. This also happens when the Map value is an entity and I use @OneToMany instead of @ElementCollection. In principle this can be done more efficiently with one query that selects all the map entries for all returned TestEntities. For Collection-valued fields OpenJPA already does this by default (openjpa.jdbc.EagerFetchMode" value="parallel") but it seems to fail on this simple entity. (Same problem with value="join").

Could I be doing something wrong? Is there an easy way to tell OpenJPA to not perform a query per entity but only one?
Or is there already any work planned on improving this (I filed it under https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-1920)?

It is a problem for us because we wish to fetch (and detach) a list of about 1900 products which takes almost 15 seconds with OpenJPA. It takes less than a second with my own native query.

Having to write only one native query wouldn't be much of a problem but the map we use is inside a reusable StringI18N entity which is referenced from several different entities (and can be deep in the object graph), so native queries are a maintenance headache.
Any help getting performance up is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: explicitly using JOIN FETCH does not help either:
"SELECT z FROM TestEntity z JOIN FETCH z.strings"
OpenJPA's TRACE still shows that it executes one SQL statement for each individual TestEntity.

Comment: Problem look the same using Hibernate 4.2.

Comment: using the @BatchSize annotation might solve the issue in Hibernate

Comment: Already tried, but no, but in my case I think this is a @OneToOne issue when loading my actual MultilingualText entity... I'll continue to search!

Comment: Interesting, I was actually using the map for the same goal in my StringI18N entity. I ended up hardcoding a String field for each of the languages we use. (Not exposed to clients of StringI18N, they still use a set(String, Locale) method). It's ugly but I think it is acceptable in our case because the languages never change.

Comment: Yes, same usage but in my case I was using another method before and it was a pain (creating custom queries each time). I've posted a question, hope an answer soon!

Answer (score 0):

It might be a pain (correction: I *know* it'll be a pain) but have you tried actually mapping your 2-field `TestEntity` as a full JPA-persisted `@Entity`?

I know that Hibernate used to treat `@ElementCollection`s rather differently to `@OneToMany`s for example - OpenJPA could well be doing something similar.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Actually I have posted on the mailing list and they say it is expected behavior at least they don't really seem to see this as a bug.

Comment: Actually I also found out that if you have a structure Company - Employee - Project and with a ManyToOne field Company.ceo, selecting companies fetches the ceo's projects with 1 query per ceo instance. Does NOT happen with OneToMany (List<Employee>). No reaction of OpenJPA on the mailing list. (My original problem was a String in multiple languages which I solved the ugly way by having a hardcoded String field for each language)